# report builder export numeric to excel

Tags: excel, export, numeric

In my report I have the field set to numeric, but when I export it to Excel, if the field is 0, it changes to a text field and fills it with 0.0000000000000000000000.  If it's not 0, it comes across as numeric.  I've tried checking for NULL, but it truly has 0 in it. I've also tried FORMATNUMBER with no luck.  This is one of the combinations I've tried.  If it's in US dollars, they want a dollar sign:
=IIF(Fields!Unit.Value = "USD", FORMATCURRENCY(Fields!JanActive.Value,2),FORMATNUMBER(Fields!JanActive.Value,2))

Answer (score 0):

This was making me crazy until I realized that I needed the Value expression to work with the Format expression.  Here's what fixed it:

Value expression
=IIF(Fields!JanActive.Value = 0, 0.0, Fields!JanActive.value)

Format expression
=IIF(Fields!Unit.Value = "USD", "'$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00)", "#0.##")

Not sure what would happen if the value is NULL, but I think that could be addressed in the value expression.